# Automate excel macro when file added to folder

Tags: windows, excel, macros

When a file is added to a folder I would like to:

1. Open file with excel eg:

`excel.exe "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"`

2. Perform macro with excel
3. Save excel file in same folder

What is the best way to achieve this on Windows 7?

Comment: You can do this with excel, but if you write the monitor code in VBA, you will need to leave the notebook open with the macro running. There is an example here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/211547-monitor-new-files-folder.html It may be better to use the OnTime function to check every second or so instead of constantly looping like the example macro does. I would probably write the code in a different language so I didn't have to leave excel open and running, but it is doable using `Application.OnTime` - I will try to write something up real quick because it's interesting.

Comment: Did you end up writing something up? Thanks so much for your help. If you post your answer below ill select it as the correct answer.